# How do I use OData $filter results on the server

Tags: odata

I have a working OData controller, which supports all the normal get/put etc.

What I want to do is pass a normal odata $filter string from the client, parse and execute the filter on the server and run some code on the resulting IEnumerable.

I've messed around with ODataQueryContext, ODataQueryOptions, FilterQueryOption etc, but not really got anywhere.

Does anyone have any working examples?

Edit:  I've added my function skeleton, just need to fill in the blanks

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetJobs(string filter)
    {
        *** How to convert the filter into IQueryable<Job> ***
        var queryable = ?????    

        var settings = new ODataQuerySettings();
        var jobs = queryOptions.ApplyTo(querable, settings) as IQueryable<Job>;

        CsvSerializer csvSerializer = new CsvSerializer();
        string csv = csvSerializer.Serialise(jobs);
        string fileName = string.Format("{0} Jobs.csv", filter);
        return CreateCsvResponseMessage(csv, fileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a scenario where I needed this sort of feature as well. This is what I came up with.

```
    private static IQueryable<T> ApplyODataFilter<T>(IQueryable<T> data, string filterString) where T : class
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<T>(typeof(T).Name);

        ODataQueryContext context = new ODataQueryContext(builder.GetEdmModel(), typeof(T), new ODataPath());

        ODataQueryOptionParser queryOptionParser = new ODataQueryOptionParser(
            context.Model,
            context.ElementType,
            context.NavigationSource,
            new Dictionary<string, string> { { "$filter", filterString } });

        FilterQueryOption filter = new FilterQueryOption(filterString, context, queryOptionParser);

        IQueryable query2 = filter.ApplyTo(data, new ODataQuerySettings());
        return query2.Cast<T>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using OData code generator to generate client side code. you can following the following blog:
[How to use OData Client Code Generator to generate client-side proxy class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/11/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspx)

The for the filter, the following is an example:

`var q2 = TestClientContext.CreateQuery<Type>("Accounts").Where(acct => acct.Birthday > new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2013, 10, 1)));`

Comment: The filter I have is an odata one, like 'IncidentId eq 5', so I don't think this solution will help.

Comment: The linq code will be translated to OData url, pass to server side. So, you want the execute the query on client side, based on response?

Comment: No.  I want to pass the odata query to the server, execute it on the server, and use the IEnumerable result also on the server.  The only part from the client is the string "$filter=Incident eq 5"

Answer (score 0):

There are some sample code in the codeplex to show how to do query.

Check this:

https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v3/ODataQueryableSample/Program.cs

---

***Update:***

There is some sample code in the controller of the sample I gave you.

Write your code as below:

```
public IQueryable<Order> Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
{
    if (queryOptions.Filter != null)
    {
        var settings = new ODataQuerySettings();
        var filterResult = queryOptions.ApplyTo(OrderList.AsQueryable(), settings) as IQueryable<Order>;
        // Use the filter result here.
    }
}
```

---

***Update 2:***
You can get the raw string of the filter from ODataQueryOptions.

```
    public IQueryable<Order> Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        string filterString = queryOptions.Filter.RawValue;
        // Use the filterString
    }
```

---

***Update 3:***

（Note: ODataProperties is an extension method in static class
`System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestMessageExtensions`）

```
        public HttpResponseMessage GetJobs(string filter)
        {
            var context = new ODataQueryContext(Request.ODataProperties().Model, typeof(Job));
            var filterQueryOption = new FilterQueryOption(filter, context);

            IQueryable<Job> queryable = GetAllJobs();
            var settings = new ODataQuerySettings();
            var jobs = filterQueryOption.ApplyTo(queryable, settings) as IQueryable<Job>;

            CsvSerializer csvSerializer = new CsvSerializer();
            string csv = csvSerializer.Serialise(jobs);
            string fileName = string.Format("{0} Jobs.csv", filter);
            return CreateCsvResponseMessage(csv, fileName);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Feng, but that's not quite what I'm after.  I don't want the HttpResponseMessage because then I'd have to parse it back from HTTP/odata. I just want the list of elements the filter would give.

Comment: I've edited my question to show where I'm having difficulty.  How do I get from a filter string to the IQueryable?

Comment: I post another update to show how to get the raw string of the filter from ODataQueryOptions.(Note: queryOptions.Filter can be null)

Comment: Hi Feng,  I already have the raw string, but I don't have the Filter!  I've edited the question to make things a little clearer.

Comment: What you want is to convert filter raw string to FilterQueryOption, not IQueryable<Job>. Check my update.

Comment: I can't find the extension assembly.  Did that extension get added recently?  My Odata.dll is version 5.6.1

Comment: The extension exists in webapi 5.2. For older version, can you try "Request.GetEdmModel()" and GetEdmModel is in static class "System.Net.Http.ODataHttpRequestMessageExtensions"